# Input a list of files & directories to be copied with ditto

Tags: bash, osx, backup

I have a short list of files and directories of which I would like to make a flat copy of using ditto in a bash shell. There are approximately 8-10 files and/or directories that need to be copied. I know that I can just create a series of conditional statements such as:

```
if [ -d ~/Documents ];
then
  ditto ~/Documents ~/BACKUP/Documents
  echo "Documents copied successfully."
else
  echo "WARNING: No documents were copied, directory does not exist in expected location."
fi
```

However, I am curious if there is a stylistically better or more efficient way of accomplishing this task? Another approach that I have considered is creating an array that holds the files/directories and then using a loop to move through the array to copy each file. Thoughts? Ideas? Insights? Best practices?

Comment: Are all the directories and files relative to your `~`? Because inserting `BACKUP/` into the path at the right position might be more "interesting" than it's worth.

Comment: All of the directories and files are relative to the ~ Would you mind explaining the impact of placing a directory called BACKUP at the ~ level to copy each of these files and directories to? Thanks for the response.

Comment: it's just that in this case, you can just do `for d in Documents Movies My\ other\ files; do ditto "~/$d" "~/BACKUP/$d"; done`, otherwise you need a second list for the target locations, which makes things more inconvenient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a loop over the directories you want to back up. Note the use of the variable `err` to keep track of any error.

```
err=0
for d in ~/Documents ~/Pictures ~/Videos; do
  if [ -d "$d" ]; then
    ditto "$d" ~/BACKUP/"${d##*/}" || err=1
  else
    echo 1>&2 "Missing directory: $d"
    err=1
  fi
done
exit $err
```

Alternatively, you can make a function that handles one directory and calls it multiple times. Note the use of `err` again.

```
backup () {
  if [ -d "$1" ]; then
    ditto "$1" "$2" || err=1
  else
    echo 1>&2 "Missing directory: $1"
    err=1
  fi
}
err=0
backup ~/Documents ~/BACKUPS/Documents
backup ~/Pictures ~/BACKUPS/Pictures
backup ~/Videos ~/BACKUPS/Videos
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the feedback. I can see how each variation has its benefits depending on the intended use. Quick question about the first example you provided, can you explain the "##*/" after the "${d"? Do you mind explaining what the hashes, asterisks, and slash translate to? Thank you.

Comment: @DeanA.Vassallo `${VAR##PATTERN}` is `$VAR` minus the longest prefix matching `PATTERN`. Here `${d##*/}` is the last directory component of `$d`, i.e. `Documents` and so on.